# Ошибка подключения к БД uniti

Tags: c#, unity3d, unity3d-ui

скачал mysql.dll версии 6.9.11 потому что только с ней адекватно проект собирался. Теперь проект собирается нормально.Но не работает подключение выдает ошибку
[image: Версия БД]

> TlsException: Handshake failed - error code: UNITYTLS_INTERNAL_ERROR, verify result: UNITYTLS_X509VERIFY_NOT_DONE
> Mono.Unity.Debug.CheckAndThrow (Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_errorstate errorState, Mono.Unity.UnityTls+unitytls_x509verify_result verifyResult, System.String context, Mono.Security.Interface.AlertDescription defaultAlert) (at :0)
> Mono.Unity.UnityTlsContext.ProcessHandshake () (at :0)
> Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) (at :0)
> (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.ProcessHandshake(Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus)
> Mono.Net.Security.AsyncHandshakeRequest.Run (Mono.Net.Security.AsyncOperationStatus status) (at :0)
> Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+d__24.MoveNext () (at :0)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable+ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Mono.Net.Security.AsyncProtocolRequest+d__23.MoveNext () (at :0)
> Rethrow as AuthenticationException: A call to SSPI failed, see inner exception.
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream+d__47.MoveNext () (at :0)
> Rethrow as AggregateException: One or more errors occurred.
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional (System.Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait (System.Int32 millisecondsTimeout, System.Threading.CancellationToken cancellationToken) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Mono.Net.Security.MobileAuthenticatedStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) (at :0)
> System.Net.Security.SslStream.AuthenticateAsClient (System.String targetHost, System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509CertificateCollection clientCertificates, System.Security.Authentication.SslProtocols enabledSslProtocols, System.Boolean checkCertificateRevocation) (at :0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.StartSSL () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.NativeDriver.Open () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Open () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.Driver.Create (MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder settings) (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.CreateNewPooledConnection () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetPooledConnection () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.TryToGetDriver () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlPool.GetConnection () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open () (at <8051f3898298485d9e8510b51445dcd7>:0)
> Components.Player+d__0.MoveNext () (at Assets/Scripts/Components/player/Player.cs:18)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Managers.GameManager+d__15.MoveNext () (at Assets/Common/GameManager.cs:106)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Managers.GameManager+d__13.MoveNext () (at Assets/Common/GameManager.cs:88)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> Managers.GameManager+d__11.MoveNext () (at Assets/Common/GameManager.cs:62)
> --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
> System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.b__6_0 (System.Object state) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
> UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at <9baebf9af86541678fd15bfdbf5f26eb>:0)
> UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks()

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно ее решить?

Comment: Взаимодействие с базой делают через [UnityWebRequest](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Networking.UnityWebRequest.html), не подключая никаких библиотек. И на прямую запрос к базе никто не делает, это не безопасно, узнав пароли из клиента, любой дурак может редактировать такую базу как ему вздумается. Всё происходит через скрипт на сервере обрабатывающий запросы.

Comment: Да мне в принципе не нужно так заморачиваться. Мне бы этот метод реализовать)

Comment: Как скажешь, тебе с этим мучаться)

Comment: Да если честно  я с этим методом  слишком долго  мучаюсь. Хочется добить . Но фиг пойми в чем проблема одна версия подключения не дает,а с другой не собирается.